# Terraform GCP vm instance create - Error 403

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

this is my first try to create VM on GCP Through terraform. here are the 2 files which i created.

provider.tf

```
provider "google" {
credentials = "${file("xxxxxx.json")}"
project = "project-1-200623"
region = "us-central1"
}
```

compute.tf

```
# Create a new instance
resource "google_compute_instance" "default" {
   name = "test"
   machine_type = "n1-standard-1"
   zone = "us-central1-a"
   boot_disk {
      initialize_params {
      image = "debian-cloud/debian-8"
   }
}
network_interface {
   network = "default"
   access_config {}
}

service_account {
   scopes = ["userinfo-email", "compute-ro", "storage-ro"]
   }
}

I am getting below error:

Error: Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* google_compute_instance.default: 1 error(s) occurred:

* google_compute_instance.default: Error loading zone 'us-central1-a': googleapi: Error 403: Required 'compute.zones.get' permission for 'projects/project-1-200623/zones/us-central1-a', forbidden.

In
```

itially i thought some syntax issue with vm image but even after changing to multiple others same issue. service account has owner permissions on project so thats i can rule out. can some one please help me here..

Appreciate the help !

Comment: What IAM roles does your user have for this project?

Comment: editor role before but changed to project owner still same result.

Comment: In that case, are the necessary apis enabled for the project? You can do this with terraform https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/google_project_services.html or experiment with the console to see first.

Comment: Hi Henry,      thank you  for input. compute, network and IAM few other apis are enabled and bunch others. Not sure if any   specific req. any chance do you   specific code which is working for you ?

Comment: Can you share the output from:
gcloud services list
and confirm the provider identity is the same as the user you say has owner permissions?

Comment: I've been able to apply your config by removing the => region = "us-central1" from the provider.tf config file.

Comment: I would also recommend to double check if the service account key and the name of the project provided in the config file provider.tf are correct. If you're trying to run a Terraform configuration on a project where the service account does not have the correct permissions (role) this may lead to a permission error message like the one you've pointed out.
So check: 
credentials = "${file("xxxxxx.json")}"
project = "project-1-200623"

Answer (score 2):

Terraform needs the organization admin permission

this is the steps to add this permission:

1. Sign in to the Google Cloud Console as a Google Workspace or Cloud Identity super administrator and navigate to the IAM & Admin page:
   [go to the admin page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin?)

2.Select the organization you want to edit:

*a.* Click the project drop-down list at the top of the page.

*b.* In the **Select from** dialog, click the organization drop-down list, and select the organization to which you want to add an Organization admin.

*c.* On the list that appears, click the organization to open its **IAM Permissions** page.

3. Click **Add**, and then enter the email address of one or more users
   you want to set as organization administrators.

4.In the **Select a role** drop-down list, select **Resource Manager > Organization Administrator**, and then click **Save**.

The Organization admin can do the following:

- Take full control of the organization. Separation of responsibilities
  between Google Workspace or Cloud Identity super administrator and
  Google Cloud administrator is established.
- Delegate responsibility over critical functions by assigning the
  relevant IAM roles.

I recommend you create a different service account to keep your projects separate, you can check how to create your service account [here](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/managing-gcp-projects-with-terraform)

Answer (score 0):

I’m with Paula. Double check you provider credentials. There’s nothing wrong with this code.

Answer (score 0):

faced same issue. I assigned following roles and it worked.
Compute Admin, Compute Instance Admin, Service Account, Service Account Admin